# NSWindow animate size change new subview with auto layout

Tags: objective-c, macos, animation, autolayout, nswindow

I have a `NSWindowController` containing several `NSViewController`. The windowController displays the view of the first viewController as a subView of the main window.

On a button click the windowController adds the next viewControllers view as subView, adds some layout constraints and animates them so that the first view moves out and the next view moves in. After the animation the first view is removed from its superView.

```
[nextController setLeftLayoutConstraint:nextLeft];
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  custom category'd property

[containerView addSubview:nextView];
[containerView addConstraints:@[nextWidth, nextHeight, nextTop, nextLeft]];

[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
    [context setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];
    [context setDuration:0.5];

    [[nextLeft animator] setConstant:[self leftOffset]];

    [[[[self currentViewController] view] animator] setAlphaValue:-0.25]; // negative alpha to shift the timing
    [[[[self currentViewController] leftLayoutConstraint] animator] setConstant:-NSWidth(containerView.frame)];
    //                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  custom category'd property
} completionHandler:^{
    [[[self currentViewController] view] setAlphaValue:1.0];
    [[[self currentViewController] view] removeFromSuperview];
    [[self currentViewController] removeFromParentViewController];

    _currentViewController = nextController;
}];
```

Now the second view is much taller than the first so it changes the windows hight as well.

Unfortunately this window frame change is not animated and the window pops ugly in the right size.

I tried getting the next views hight first to then animate all constraints or something like this. Unfortunately the views are not in the correct size before the animation is done.

Is there any way to animate the window change as well?

Comment: It seems redundant to use removeFromSuperview as well as removeFromParentViewController, and odd to invoke viewDidDisappear and viewDidAppear explicitly.

Comment: `removeFromParentViewController` does not remove the view but tells the viewController that it does not belong to the parent anymore. `viewDidAppear` was a leftover from my tests :)